# gcc support for cbegin and cend method

Tags: c++, gcc

Which version of the gcc compiler supports free `const_iterator` methods for containers, e.g.: `cbegin`, `cend`, `crbegin`, `crend`. I use gcc 4.6.1 with c++0x features enabled by `-std=c++0x` flag but these methods could not be resolved in my code.

Comment: Are you getting any errors on using these methods or they are not behaving in the way they should?

Comment: Error: "Method 'cbegin' could not be resolved" Error By Eclipse IDE 1.4.1 with -std=c++0x and gcc compiler 4.6.1 on fedora 15 x86_x64

Comment: Post a complete example please that produces the error. I'm beginning to think that your error lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no free functions `cbegin`/`cend` in the standard, nor are there any of the reverse versions. You can always use a cast, though, to get the constant iterator:

```
auto it = std::begin(static_cast<T const &>(x));
```

Using `std::add_const` from `<type_traits>` you should even be able to rig up something fairly general if you need this a lot.

---

The container member functions `cbegin`/`crbegin` etc are all part of C++11, and GCC has been supporting those for some time; quite possibly since 4.3 (when C++11 support was first began). GCC 4.6 definitely supports those; if you're having trouble, post the troublesome code.

Comment: In the document ISO/IEC 14882:2011(E) of International Standards, Iterators section 21.4.3 page 655 it has mentined to const iterators such as cbegin and cend does that mean the standard interface should support these methods.

Comment: @AMCoded: Those are member functions. Were you asking about those? I thought you were talking about the free functions `std::begin` etc.

Comment: Yes I mean member functions that comes with container classes like vector or list

Comment: Error: "Method 'cbegin' could not be resolved" Error By Eclipse IDE 1.4.1 with -std=c++0x and gcc compiler 4.6.1 on fedora 15 x86_x64

Comment: Does this mean that my favorite reference [cppreference.com/begin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) is wrong?

Comment: @Mankka: No, why? Did you see the "since C++14"? The question is about GCC's `c++0x`, aka C++11.

Comment: @KerrekSB Right, I was confused. However, my GCC 4.9.1 does not support them with `-std=gnu++1y` and I didn't find any mention of them  in the [status page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html).

Answer (score 1):

My experiment shows that by default "`cbegin`" is not available (from like `<vector>` `<map>` STL containers). Unless you specify either `--std=c++0x` or `--std=c++11`

Here's my expriment on GCC 4.8:

http://ascii.io/a/4539

If your compiler can't support those `--std` switches (like I'm doing on some cross-platform toolchains), you may just use something like:

```
for (std::vector<string>::const_iterator it = vec.begin(), ite = vec.end();
                                         it != ite; ++it) {
    /* ... ... */
}
```

This works with GCC versions that have no support of C++11's "auto" keyword feature.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me (GCC 4.6.0):

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> vec;
  auto it = vec.cbegin();
  // int& val = *it;  // gives compiler error, as expected
}
```

The member functions are also present in `stl_vector.h`.

Comment: I have installed gcc 4.6.1 in fedora 15 x86_x64 and using eclipse IDE 1.4.1 I with -std=C++0x flag for c++ Builder of the IDE and get the error "Method 'cbegin' could not be resolved" for the above code, so what did I have wrong I can't understand.

Comment: @AMCoded: can you try building from the command line to see if it's a problem with your Eclipse configuration or your GCC install/configuration?  `g++ -std=c++0x foo.cpp`

Comment: yes, of course I have tried building them in command line but I get the same error, I could use all the c++11 features except this one, I don't know what's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add your own?

```
template< class C > 
auto cbegin( C& c ) -> decltype(c.cbegin());

template< class C > 
auto cbegin( const C& c ) -> decltype(c.cbegin())
```

Comment: I am looking for cbegin and cend methods of the continer classes, would it solve my problem.

Comment: Ahh, sorry.  I know the standalone version of cbegin() and cend() are missing from the language.  This would add it, but it doesn't fix the problem if the container does not support it.